# How to link static library in GitHubActions from different repos

Tags: c++, github-actions, repo

I am setting up actions for my organization, we have an internal library that is statically linked against our projects.
This static library is in one repo, and locally it would be someplace like `/opt/MY-LIB`
I have successfully set up the GitHub action for building the static library.

What I want to do now is to be able to use the .a file that it generates when building the projects that are on different repos.

The project is built using a python build script that underneath calls CMake and make.
When calling the build script from the project it will assume that the .a file is located under `/opt/MY-LIB/build/<<CONFIG>>/lib`, as that's the path specified in the CMakeLists.txt

this is the .yml file that I have come up with, but it does not work:
when it calls:

```yml
    - name: check MY-LIB
      run: | 
        ls /opt/MY-LIB
```

it says that the path is not found, but when running the library build it exists, is there a way to "preserve" the state?

```yml
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ,"test_automated_build"]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build_my_lib:
    uses: MY-ORG/MY-LIB/.github/workflows/c-cpp.yml@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: check MY-LIB
      run: | 
        ls /opt/MY-LIB
```

An the worfklow file on the library is something like:

```yml
name: C/C++ CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ,"development","feature/automated_build_template_project"]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main","development" ]
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        build_type: [Debug, Release]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest


    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: carlosperate/arm-none-eabi-gcc-action@v1
      - run: arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install GitPython colorama
      - name: Set up MY-LIB
        run: cp -r ../* /opt/
      - name: Display MY-LIB
        working-directory: /opt/MY-LIB/
        run: ls 
      - name: Invoking python
        working-directory: /opt/MY-LIB/tools
        run: python3 build.py -bb ${{matrix.build_type}}
```

As I mentioned the build of the static library works fine.

I have searched the documentation from GitHub but when using reusable workflows it talks mostly about secrets, any way to do this?

Worst case scenario I assume I could use a docker image, but I have no idea about how that would go

Comment: You're building the lib in a runner instance, and trying to access it in a different runner instance, that's the reason why it doesn't appear on the second job. You would need to perform all operations in the same job for it to work, or share an artifact between jobs.

Comment: Could I call it from the project that uses the library?
Or just use the artifact approach, but I'm still unsure about how to it in within different repos.

Comment: When you use the actions/checkout in the reusable, it should checkout the original repo (the one calling the reusable), so I understand you could update the reusable to perform the operation using the library directly, yes.

Comment: to checkout  to the original repo I would use my-org/my-repo/actions/checkout@ref ??
Also it's a shame that I only uploads the latest job, so in my case it only uploads the Debug one

Comment: The `uses: actions/checkout@v3` in the reusable workflow should checkout the repo calling the reusable, you shouldn't need to update anything here. Just add the `ls /opt/MY-LIB` command at the end of the reusable workflow.